# set one field equal to another

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<form>
<input id="A" name="B">
<input id="C" name="D">
</form>
```

And I need to set the second input equal to the first whenever the first input is changed.
Something like:

```
$(function() {
   $('input#A').change(function() {
   $('input#C').val(this.text);
   });
});
```

Comment: You should be using the selector #A rather than [tag name]#A. It uses getElementById whereas input#A will loop over input tags.

Comment: What's wrong with your own code snippet, @Phillip? Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
   var myInput = $('#A');
   myInput.change(function() {
       $('#C').val(myInput.val());
   });
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that often, in jQuery, the difference from a “getter” to a “setter” is just one parameter. myObj.val() vs. myObj.val(putThis), myObj.html() vs. myObj.html("<p>hi</p>"), myObj.attr('cellspacing') vs. myObj.attr('cellspacing', '5') et cetera.